# Конвертация даты в unix timestamp средствами mysql или php

Tags: php, mysql

Есть ли способ конвертировать месяца в unix timestamp с помощью mysql?

Я использую такую конструкцию в запросе `EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM var1.`date`) as dates`
Получаю данные 202201, 202202 и т.д. Можно ли эти цифры конвертировать unix_timestamp или бесполезно?

Comment: что мешает сделать просто `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(x)` для первого дня месяца, видимо?

Comment: Если бы не проверял, то не задавал бы вопрос. UNIX_TIMESTAMP(x) возвращает TIMESTAMP для даты типа "2017-12-13 12:11:16.0". Для 201712 это уже не работает

Comment: Как минимум этот костыль `unix_timestamp(EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM var1.`date`)) as dates` возвращает null. Я конечно не спец по sql, поэтому ищу ответ вопрос))

Comment: зато если к `202201` присоединить `01` в качестве даты, то вполне себе возвращает `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM NOW()),'01'))`

Comment: Так работает:) Спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы сделал так:

```
select UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_format(var1.date, '%y-%m-01'));
```

[MySQL UNIX_TIMESTAMP DATE_FORMAT](https://sqlize.online/sql/mysql57/3a4ede280f3dabc5c7fb8bf9cefe289a/)